# deep learning: class labels not in a sequential range

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

If class labels are not in a perfect sequential range, is that a problem? Like normally class labels are assigned as an integer number starting from 0-N (0, 1, 2, 3, ... N).

If I use labeling, not in that incremental way but any set of numbers will the model performance vary? Such as for 10 class dataset instead of using 0-10, use [0,20,19,113,19,9,7,8,3,4].

Any comment is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: do I have to use class labels in a range like [0-10] or they can be any set of 10 integers as mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the task you're performing. For classification, there is functionally no difference between a range of [0-9] for 10 classes or using the range you're suggesting, since the model will have an output layer of size 10, and the translation to class labels afterwards is arbitrary. As such neither the labels nor the order matters, as long as they are similarly translated during training and inference.

If the labels have numerical relations (i.e. the label 4 is twice as much of something compared to the label 2), you're not doing classification, but regression.